# Rest API call stuck on park method in Unsafe class with WebClient in Spring WebFlux, what could be the cause and how can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, spring-webclient

I am calling a rest-api using webclient, the call is stuck after showing this message in logs

```
thread=reactor-http-nio-6 level=DEBUG logger=reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient trace_id= span_id= message="[357a6a9a] REGISTERED"
```

It is stuck at park method in Unsafe class from Java.

Java Version -- 11
Spring webflux -- 5.3.25
reactor-netty-http -- 1.0.27

Now in same application I tried the same endpoint with rest template and it is working fine. And also I am calling another endpoint with webclient at application start and that is working.
There is no issue with webclient approach, because same approach I am using in other applications which calls 5-6 different host and endpoint and there it is working fine.

this is code I am using

```
bookingChangeServiceWebClient.put().uri("bookingChange")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).bodyValue(
                orderChangeEventRequest,
            ).retrieve().bodyToMono(String::class.java).subscribe({response -> countDownLatch.countDown()}, {error -> countDownLatch.countDown()})
```

I tried also with `awaitBody()` instead of subscribe,but the issue is same.

UPDATE --
it is only working with bare subscribe without any lambda function.

Checked the thread dump while calling with awaitBody() got this

```
reactor-http-nio-6" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 waiting on condition
```